# how to generate control flow graph of a c program by gcc 3.4.5?

Tags: gcc

I type the following command in the command line in order to generate control flow graph for a c program by gcc 3.4.5 but I couldn't find the result files.
In addition, how do I see the control flow graph garphicallyy?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include your command-line... I assume -fprofile-arcs.  The output file location is described in the gcc manpage:

```
    ... Each object file's auxname is
    generated from the name of the output file, if explicitly speci-
    fied and it is not the final executable, otherwise it is the base-
    name of the source file. In both cases any suffix is removed (e.g.
    foo.gcda for input file dir/foo.c, or dir/foo.gcda for output file
    specified as -o dir/foo.o).
```

So, output is written alongside the object files - in their directories.  If you compile source directly to an executable, you'll find the profiling output in the directory the compiler wrote the executable to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcc -fdump-tree-cfg <Source.c>` for the control flow graph.

Refer the link for GUI.
[Geting Control Flow Graph from ANSI C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393985/geting-control-flow-graph-from-ansi-c-code/17844310#17844310)