# Getting Control Flow Graph from ANSI C code

Tags: c, gcc, graph, ansi-c

I'm building tool for testing ansi c applications. Simply load code, view control flow graph, run test, mark all vertexes which were hit. I'm trying to build CFG all by myself from parsing code. Unfortunately It gets messed up if code is nested. GCC gives ability to get CFG from compiled code. I might write parser for its output, but I need line numbers for setting breakpoints. Is there way for getting line numbers when outputting Control Flow Graph with `-fdump-tree-cfg` or `-fdump-tree-vcg`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I've made some more research and it is not hard to get line numbers for nodes. Just add `lineno` option to one of those options to get it. So use `-fdump-tree-cfg-lineno` or `-fdump-tree-vcg-lineno`. It took me some time to check if those numbers are **reliable**. In case of graph in **VCG** format label of each node contains **two numbers**. Those are line numbers for start and end of code portion represented by this node.

Answer (score 21):

For the control flow graph of a C Program you could look at existing Python parsers for C:

- [PyCParser](https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser)
- [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)
- [pyclibrary](https://github.com/albertz/pyclibrary) (fork of [pyclibrary](https://launchpad.net/pyclibrary) )
- [joern](https://github.com/fabsx00/joern)
- [CoFlo](http://coflo.sourceforge.net/wordpress/) C/C++ control flow graph generator and analyzer

Call graphs are a closely related construct to control flow graphs.
There are several approaches available to create call graphs (function dependencies) for C code.
This might prove of help for progressing with control flow graph generation.
Ways to create dependency graphs in C:

- Using [cflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_cflow):
- cflow +[pycflow2dot](https://pypi.org/project/pycflow2dot/) +[dot](http://www.graphviz.org) (GPL, BSD) cflow is robust, because it can handle code which cannot compile, e.g. missing includes. If preprocessor directives are heavily used, it may need the `--cpp` option to preprocess the code.
- cflow + [cflow2dot](https://code.google.com/p/cflow2dot/) + dot  (GPL v2, GPL v3, Eclipse Public License (EPL) v1)   (note that cflow2dot needs some path fixing before it works)
- cflow +[cflow2dot.bash](http://codingtorus.wordpress.com/5310713) (GPL v2, ?)
- cflow +[cflow2vcg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cflow2vcg/) (GPL v2 , GPL v2)
- [enhanced cflow](https://github.com/vishalkanaujia/cflow) (GPL v2) with list to exclude symbols from graph
- Using [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net):
- cscope (BSD)
- cscope +[callgraphviz](https://github.com/chihchun/callgraphviz) +dot +xdot
- cscope +vim [CCTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368) (C Call-Tree Explorer)
- cscope +[ccglue](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccglue/)
- cscope +[CodeQuery](https://ruben2020.github.io/codequery/) for C, C++, Python & Java
- cscope +[Python html producer](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-January/419337.html)
- cscope +[calltree.sh](http://toolchainguru.blogspot.com/2011/03/c-calltrees-in-bash-revisited.html)
- [ncc](http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/%7Esxanth/ncc/) (cflow like)
- [KCachegrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io) (KDE dependency viewer)
- [Calltree](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Calltree)

The following tools unfortunately require that the code be compilable, because they depend on output from gcc:

- [CodeViz](https://github.com/petersenna/codeviz) (GPL v2) (weak point: needs compilable source, because it uses gcc to dump cdepn files)
- [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org) +[egypt](https://www.gson.org/egypt/) +dot (GPL v*, Perl = GPL | Artistic license, EPL v1) (`egypt` uses `gcc` to produce `RTL`, so fails for any buggy source code, or even in case you just want to focus on a single file from a larger project. Therefore, it is not very useful compared to the more robust `cflow`-based toolchains. Note that egypt has by default good support for excluding library calls from the graph, to make it cleaner.

Also, file dependency graphs for C/C++ can be created with [`crowfood`](https://github.com/neothemachine/crowfood).

Comment: Call graph is not what I need. I need to visual branches in code. I have to show all loops and decision points in code to user. I made my own parser for VCG, but I will check tools which you posted.

Answer (score 2):

**Dynamic analysis methods**

In this answer I describe a few dynamic analysis methods.

Dynamic methods actually run the program to determine the call graph.

The opposite of dynamic methods are static methods, which try to determine it from the source alone without running the program.

Advantages of dynamic methods:

- catches function pointers and virtual C++ calls. These are present in large numbers in any non-trivial software.

Disadvantages of dynamic methods:

- you have to run the program, which might be slow, or require a setup that you don't have, e.g. cross-compilation
- only functions that were actually called will show. E.g., some functions could be called or not depending on the command line arguments.

**KcacheGrind**

https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html

Test program:

```
int f2(int i) { return i + 2; }
int f1(int i) { return f2(2) + i + 1; }
int f0(int i) { return f1(1) + f2(2); }
int pointed(int i) { return i; }
int not_called(int i) { return 0; }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int (*f)(int);
    f0(1);
    f1(1);
    f = pointed;
    if (argc == 1)
        f(1);
    if (argc == 2)
        not_called(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
sudo apt-get install -y kcachegrind valgrind

# Compile the program as usual, no special flags.
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -o main -std=c99 main.c

# Generate a callgrind.out.<PID> file.
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./main

# Open a GUI tool to visualize callgrind data.
kcachegrind callgrind.out.1234
```

You are now left inside an awesome GUI program that contains a lot of interesting performance data.

On the bottom right, select the "Call graph" tab. This shows an interactive call graph that correlates to performance metrics in other windows as you click the functions.

To export the graph, right click it and select "Export Graph". The exported PNG looks like this:

[image]

From that we can see that:

- the root node is `_start`, which is the actual ELF entry point, and contains glibc initialization boilerplate
- `f0`, `f1` and `f2` are called as expected from one another
- `pointed` is also shown, even though we called it with a function pointer. It might not have been called if we had passed a command line argument.
- `not_called` is not shown because it didn't get called in the run, because we didn't pass an extra command line argument.

The cool thing about `valgrind` is that it does not require any special compilation options.

Therefore, you could use it even if you don't have the source code, only the executable.

`valgrind` manages to do that by running your code through a lightweight "virtual machine".

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**`gcc -finstrument-functions` + etrace**

https://github.com/elcritch/etrace

`-finstrument-functions` [adds callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176284/why-doesnt-finstrument-functions-work-for-me), etrace parses the ELF file and implements all callbacks.

I couldn't get it working however unfortunately: [Why doesn't `-finstrument-functions` work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176284/why-doesnt-finstrument-functions-work-for-me)

Claimed output is of format:

```
\-- main
|   \-- Crumble_make_apple_crumble
|   |   \-- Crumble_buy_stuff
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   \-- Crumble_prepare_apples
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_skin_and_dice
|   |   \-- Crumble_mix
|   |   \-- Crumble_finalize
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   \-- Crumble_cook
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_bake
```

Likely the most efficient method besides specific hardware tracing support, but has the downside that you have to recompile the code.

Comment: Original question stated I had source code and was totally fine with recompile as it was tool for dynamic analysis on source code.