# Generate a dependency diagram for c++ codes/projects

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, diagram

I have a massive C++ code to probe into from github and it would be helpful if I can generate a dependency diagram for the code base. Ideally I would like to know what function triggers other ones in the code and where are they located. Is there any program/software that does this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [call graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph). One option is [`cflow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_cflow) together with [`pycflow2dot`](https://pypi.org/project/pycflow2dot) and [`dot`](http://www.graphviz.org). More options can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844310/1959808

Example C file:

```c
/*
 * simple demo for pycflow2dot, use with:
 *    cflow2dot -i example.c -f png
 * for help:
 *    cflow2dot -h
 */

#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello(char *s)
{
    printf(s);
}

void hello_1()
{
    say_hello("Hello 1 !\n");
}

void hello_2()
{
    say_hello("Hello 2 !\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    hello_1();
    hello_2();
}
```

From this file, with the command:

```sh
cflow2dot -i example.c -f png
```

the following image is produced:

[image: 1]